# How to propagate errors through catchError() properly?

Tags: rxjs, angular-http, rxjs6

I wrote a function that is `pipe`-able:

```ts
HandleHttpBasicError<T>()
{
    return ((source:Observable<T>) => {
        return source.pipe(
            catchError((err:any) => {
                let msg = '';
                if(err && err instanceof HttpErrorResponse)
                {
                    if(err.status == 0)
                        msg += "The server didn't respond";
                }
                throw {
                    err,
                    msg
                } as CustomError
            })
        )
        
    })
}
```

I can use this function this way in my `HttpService`:

```ts
checkExist(id:string)
{
    return this.http.head<void>(environment.apiUrl + 'some_url/' + id)
        .pipe(
            HandleHttpBasicError(),
            catchError((err:CustomError) => {
                if(err.msg)
                    throw err.msg;
                if(err.err.status == HttpStatusCodes.NOT_FOUND)
                    throw("It doesn't exist.");
                throw(err);
            })
            
        )
}
```

It's working great. When I subscribe to `checkExist()`, I get a good error message, because `HandleHttpBasicError` first catches an error and throws it to the service's `catchError()`, which throwes the error message because it was not `null`.

This way, it allows me to have a global `catchError()` which handles error messages that will always be the same. In the future, I will do it in a `HttpHandler`, but that's not the point here.

Is it ok to chain the errors with the `throw` keyword?

I tried to return `Observable.throwError()`, but the browser said

> Observable.throwError is not a function

My imports are `import {Observable, of, throwError} from 'rxjs';`.

Isn't it better to do this:

```ts
return ((source:Observable<T>) => {
        return source.pipe(
            catchError((err:any) => {
                msg = '';
                ...
                return of({err, msg} as CustomError)
                /* instead of
                throw(err)
                -or-
                return Observable.throwError(err) (which doesn't work)
                */
            })
        )
        
    })
```

?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

> Is it ok to chain the errors with the throw keyword ?

Yes, it's totally fine. rxjs try-catches such cases and converts it into an error notification.

> I tryed to return Observable.throwError() but the browser say "Observable.throwError is not a function"

With rxjs6, the `Observable` prototype is no longer modified to contain operators or these »creation operators«, instead they are exposed as standalone functions. You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md), but the gist of it is that you'd just `return throwError(…)`, e.g.

```js
return source$.pipe(
  catchError(err => err.code === 404 
    ? throwError("Not found")
    : throwError(err)
  )
)
```

Comment: The link provided no longer works. https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/throwError

Comment: https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/catchError they throw using throw 'err' and they don't use throwError operator